# RSS parser for Node.JS

Tags: javascript, parsing, node.js, modules, rss

I would like someone to review this code and tell if it can be done better, or if the code is elegant and simple enough for the task at hand.

I used code climate and I got 4/4 and my test coverage is 96%, yet I would like a professional opinion about it.

```
'use strict';

var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var FeedParser = require('feedparser');
var http = require('http');
var PromisePolyfill = require('promise');
var urlEncode = require('urlencode');


/**
  * Extracts a valid url from the RSS Feed Item, taking into account exception urls
  * @param {string} content - the item to be analyzed
  * @returns {string} - the valid url inside the item
*/
function getValidURL(content) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(content),
      responseUrl;

    $('a').each(function(i, e) {
        if ( $(e).attr('href').indexOf('reddit.com') === -1 &&
          $(e).attr('href').indexOf('imgur.com') === -1 ) {
            responseUrl = $(e).attr('href');
        }
    });
    return responseUrl;
}

/**
  * Parses a RSS stream into an Object
  * @param {string} rssUrl - RSS url to fetch the stream
  * @returns {Object} - the Object with meta and item information
*/
exports.parseRss = function(rssUrl) {
    var responseObject = {
      title: '',
      link: '',
      image: '',
      items: []
    };

    return new PromisePolyfill(function(resolve, reject) {
        http.get(rssUrl, function(resGet) {
            resGet.pipe(new FeedParser({}))
                .on('error', function(error) {
                    reject(error.message);
                })
                .on('meta', function(meta) {
                    responseObject.title = meta.title;
                    responseObject.link = meta.link;
                })
                .on('readable', function() {
                    var stream = this,
                      item,
                      validUrl = '';

                    while ((item = stream.read())) {
                        validUrl = getValidURL(item.description);
                        item.title2 = urlEncode(item.title);

                        if (validUrl) {
                            var ep = {
                                'title': item.title,
                                'title2': item.title2,
                                'mediaUrl': item.link,
                                'newUrl': validUrl,
                                'date': item.date
                            };

                            responseObject.items.push(ep);
                        }

                    }
                })
                .on('end', function() {
                    resolve(responseObject);
                });
        })
        .on('error', function(error) {
            reject(error.message);
        });
    });
};
```

And its respective test file:

```
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;
var rssParser = require('../../modules/rssParser');

var response,
  responsePT;

chai.should();
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);


describe('rssParser Module', function() {

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        response = new PassThrough();
        responsePT = new PassThrough();
        sinon.stub(http, 'get');
        done();
    });

    afterEach(function(done) {
        http.get.restore();
        done();
    });

    it('should return valid object when a valid url is passed', function(done) {

        var data = fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/rssResponse1.xml', 'utf8');

        response.write(data);
        response.end();

        http.get.callsArgWith(1, response)
                .returns(responsePT);

        rssParser.parseRss('http://www.reddit.com/r/science/.rss')
        .done(function(responseObject) {
            responseObject.should.be.an('object');
            responseObject.items.length.should.equal(3);
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should return empty items when a valid url is not found', function(done) {

        var data = fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/notFound.xml', 'utf8');

        response.write(data);
        response.end();

        http.get.callsArgWith(1, response)
                .returns(responsePT);

        rssParser.parseRss('http://www.reddit.com/r/urlnotfound/.rss')
        .done(function(responseObject) {
            responseObject.should.be.an('object');
            responseObject.items.length.should.equal(0);
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should throw an error with an empty response', function(done) {

        var data = '';

        response.write(data);
        response.end();

        http.get.callsArgWith(1, response)
                .returns(responsePT);

        rssParser.parseRss('http://www.reddit.com/r/emptyresponse/.rss')
        .then(function() {
            // Not returning a valid responseObject, should catch the error
        }, function(error) {
            error.should.equal('Not a feed');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I admit I haven't used cheerio before, but it looks like a good tool! The code looks decent - it appears that it will resolve and reject the promise when appropriate.

I see a couple places that can be simplified. For example:

> ```
> $('a').each(function(i, e) {
>     if ( $(e).attr('href').indexOf('reddit.com') === -1 &&
>       $(e).attr('href').indexOf('imgur.com') === -1 ) {
>         responseUrl = $(e).attr('href');
>     }
> });
> ```

Instead of selecting all anchor tags and then checking to see if the *href* attribute doesn't contain one of two strings, those conditions could be used to only select such anchor tags. This can be achieved using the [`:not()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) with an [attribute selector `*=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
const links = $('a:not([href*="reddit.com"]):not([href*="imgur.com"])');
if (links.length) {
    responseUrl = links.attr('href');
}
```

When I tested this with the sample data there was only one such anchor tag, but if there happen to be multiple, should `responseUrl` be set to the first, last or other?

---

The only other simplification I see is this:

> ```
> on('end', function() {
>    resolve(responseObject);
> });
> ```

can be simplified to:

```
on('end', resolve.bind(null, responseObject));
```

using a [partially applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions).